# Знак "Глас народа" позволяет набрать только 38 пунктов

Tags: поддержка, дефект, faq, статус-так-задумано

Как набрать 40 пунктов голосов, если у меня максимум только 38 раз позволяет провести голосование?

Уже несколько дней пробовал набрать это количество голосов и всякий раз индикатор получения знака останавливается на отметке в 38 пунктов.

Из-за чего такое может происходить?

Может ли это быть ошибкой системы или это мои какие-то неверные действия?

Где можно посмотреть ошибки, которые я делаю?

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что из 40 голосов, выданных на день, не более 30 могут быть потрачены на ответы. Чтобы использовать все 40, нужно включить в рацион не менее 10 голосов за ответы. (Ну или против, это по вкусу.)